# I need someone to explain permutations of a string to me

Tags: vb.net

Over the summer I decided to write a program that would solve an anagram by using all possible combinations of the letters in a word that you would enter. I managed to do it but in such a way that it could work out a 3-4 letter word out quickly but anything more and it would take ages! Anyway, after asking on some other site for help some guy/girl fixed my problem by writing some code for me.

At the time I didn't understand it even though it had been annotated and I had another look today to see if I could get anything from it but alas, nothing...

I've been researching permutations for about 2 hours now and I'm getting nowhere - the code is on the internet but no-one has explained it well enough (or simply enough) for me to grasp the concept. I will post the code that I have yet to understand below and if anyone can explain this in detail and how it works then it would be great!

```
Public Sub permutations(ByVal WordLength As Integer, ByVal SplitLetters As List(Of Char), ByVal word As String)

    If WordLength = 1 Then
        results.Add(word & SplitLetters(0))   
        count += 1                            

        If count Mod updateCount = 0 Then
            ldBar.Value = ((count / pCombinations) * 100)
        End If
    Else

        For i = 0 To WordLength - 1

            Dim newWord = word & SplitLetters(i)

            Dim newSplitLetters As List(Of Char) = New List(Of Char)(SplitLetters)
            newSplitLetters.RemoveAt(i)
            Call permutations(WordLength - 1, newSplitLetters, newWord)
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The method gets all permutations by using recursion.

Given a word, for example `FUBAR`, it uses each character in turn as the first character and gets all possible permutations by combining that will all permutation for the remaining characters:

```
F + permutatons(UBAR)
U + permutatons(FBAR)
B + permutatons(FUAR)
A + permutatons(FUBR)
R + permutatons(FUBA)
```

For that first recursive call it gets all permutations that starts with each character:

```
U + permutatons(BAR)
B + permutatons(UAR)
A + permutatons(UBR)
R + permutatons(UBA)
```

And so on. When it gets down to a single character string, all possible permutations is just that single character.